# Reuse of Java class object

Tags: java

I have  a class Order as shown below :

```
public class Order {

    private List<OrderLine> orderLines = new ArrayList<OrderLine>();


    public void add(OrderLine o) throws Exception {
        if (o == null) {
            System.err.println("ERROR - Order is NULL");

        }
        orderLines.add(o);
    }
    public void clear() {
      this.orderLines.clear();

    }
}
```

Now in my main I want to use one variable of order and update list and print the output

**My Main class code:**

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Map<String, Order> allOrders = new HashMap<String, Order>();

        //Build Order 1
        Order order = new Order();
        order.add(new OrderLine(new Item("book", (float) 12.49), 1));
        order.add(new OrderLine(new Item("Pen", (float) 14.99), 1));

        allOrders.put("Order 1", order);
        order.clear();



        //Build Order 2

        // Reuse cart for an other order


        order.add(new OrderLine(new Item("imported box of chocolate", 10), 1));
        order.add(new OrderLine(new Item("perfume", (float) 47.50), 1));
        allOrders.put("Order 2", order);
        order.clear();
}
```

Here I am creating one of the order object and addign details and adding this to list.Now Clearing the data in the object and updating the object with new order details but the first order details are also updated with second order details.I think Order object is Pass by reference.How to achieve object reuse avoiding pass by reference and have all order details??

Regards,
Nagasree.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is Java "pass-by-reference" or "pass-by-value"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value)

Comment: Java is, and will always be pass-by-value. http://javadude.com/articles/passbyvalue.htm

Comment: I do not believe you have done enough research regarding your answer, the problem is very simple

Answer (score 1):

If you add the same `Order` instance to the `Map` multiple times, all the values in your `Map` will be identical.

Instead of calling `clear()`, create a new `Order` :

replace

```
order.clear();
```

with

```
order = new Order ();
```

It would make sense to use your paradigm of reusing a single object if you didn't add that object to the `Map`.

For example, you can use a single `StringBuilder` instance to generate `String`s that would be added to the `Map` :

```
Map<Integer,String> map = new HashMap<>();
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(128);
sb.append("one");
map.put(1,sb.toString());

sb.setLength(0); // equivalent to your clear()
sb.append("two"); // reuse same StringBuilder instance
map.put(2,sb.toString());
```

Comment: Actually  challenge is not to create another object of Order and achieve.I thought may be I am missing some concept of java.

Comment: @NAGASREE If you must put the `Order` instance a value in the `Map`, you can't use a single `Order` object. If you only want to print the data represented by these orders, you can use a single `Order` instance, but put in the `Map` `order.toString()` (assuming your Order class overrides `toString()`.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

- you create an object for your order.
- you put this object in a list
- you edit this same object
- you (re) put this same object in the list

-> your list contains 2 times the same object

in fact:

> updating the object with new order details

should be

> updating the object with **another** order details

Answer (score -1):

You need something like [Singleton](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2073352/core-java/simply-singleton.html)

Or just do that:

```
order = new Order ();
```

Comment: singleton is exactly the opposite of you second suggestion